# python telegram bot - how to see if my bot is admin in the public channel? -

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I want to check if my bot is admin in the channel by **channel id**.

For more story I am getting channel id from forwarded channel messages. I want to check if bot is in the channel and is admin.

Answer (score 0):

seems like

```
bot.get_chat_administrators(channel_id)
```

works for public channels